# Does codeigniter share mysql sessions between http request

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there any way that 2 different http requests to use same mysql connection/session when using codeigniter's database class (e.g. $this->db)? I heard that some frameworks does that, however, my project's well being depends on the hope that codeigniter doesn't do that. Because, I am creating temporary tables, and each request need to have a seperate temporary table, rather than sharing them. Can anyone clarify?

### edit

I am also using table locking.

Comment: instead of asking SO for workaround to a patch of a bugfix in your solution , you should have explained the problem, and asked us for a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES. If your framework configuration uses persistent connection, then all temporary tables will be present from one call to another. If you are not using persistent connection then db connection will automatically get killed at the end of the script and your next script will start fresh. If you are relying on temp tables in your calls and they need to be different, be careful.  Per MYSQL's site:

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the > connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table
>   name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

You mentioned frameworks, so here's an example for you in CodeIgniter. Create a controller. Let's call is CTRL and then a bunch of methods step1, step2, step3, step4. You only need 1 and 2 really but I went a little overboard:

```
function step1()
{
    $this->your_model->db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (col1 int null);");
    $this->your_model->db->query("INSERT INTO test values (1);");
}

function step2()
{
    $res = $this->your_model->db->query("SELECT * from test;");
    print_r($res->result_array());

}
function step3()
{
    $this->your_model->db->query("INSERT INTO test values (2);");
    $this->your_model->db->query("INSERT INTO test values (3);");

}
function step4()
{
    $res = $this->your_model->db->query("SELECT * from test;");
    print_r($res->result_array());

}
```

If you were to run the above with 'pconnect' set to TRUE, by doing these one at at time:

```
http://yoursite/CTRL/step1
http://yoursite/CTRL/step2
http://yoursite/CTRL/step3
http://yoursite/CTRL/step4
```

You will get your data inserted and then displayed from one call to another, meaning your TEMP table still lives there.

Now, change 'pconnect' to FALSE, bounce your server and re-run the above, you get:

```
Table 'yourdb.test' doesn't exist

SELECT * from test;

Filename: C:\yourpath\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Comment: ... and unless you have separate MySQL users for each user in your web application, you'll have another headache when multiple clients start to use it and it's not just you testing it. Yes - technically, everything described by @Alexey Gerasimov is correct, but it's not a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, and as such - each PHP script is executed and terminated on separate requests, so there's no way to maintain any persistent connection between requests, unless it's handled by an external process. Even if you use HTTP/1.1 with Keep-alive on, even though multiple HTTP requests are handled by a single Apache (for example) process/thread and connection - separate requests still represent different script executions. This doesn't have to do anything with CodeIgniter.
However, if you've set pconnect on for your database connection, PHP will try to reuse the same database connection when possible. This still doesn't mean that it's the same session.

Comment: You are wrong, I am afraid. PHP is using persistent mysql connection all the way.

Comment: PHP and everything else that connects to MySQL can use persistent connections - yes, but each separate HTTP request represents a DIFFERENT PHP process.

Comment: Well, I am currently working on a project that involves such persistency between requests (not MySQL related, but still ...) and I can guarantee that. pconnect leaves an open socket descriptor to be re-used again by PHP, but it's simply that - a socket. It doesn't maintain "sessions", cannot hold transaction states, etc. and still requires re-authentication.

Comment: how php knows what open socket to use?

Comment: I don't know exactly how it's done, so I can't go that far with explanations, but the only thing that it's useful for is saving system resources. You can read about it at http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php